# How should i click this type of log in with selenuim.py

Tags: python

im not sure how i should click this button be cause ive been trying to use `content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'content')` but this just wont work. this part of the full code isnt suppose to log in but just press the loggin button.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

userUser = input('username: ')
userPass = input('Password: ')
NOF = input('insert amount of people to follow: ')

NOF = 10

chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\lukee\Downloads\Follower\chromedriver.exe'  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver_path))
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Flogin%2F%3F__coig_login%3D1')

time.sleep(2)

username = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
password = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')

username.send_keys(userUser) 
password.send_keys(userPass) 



time.sleep(50)
```

this is the screen it goes to https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyFYj.jpg

i dont know what to put here

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[type='submit']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use find_element_by_xpath() (I don't know will be work or not, you must be test)

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


userUser = input('username: ')
userPass = input('Password: ')
NOF = input('insert amount of people to follow: ')

NOF = 10

chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\lukee\Downloads\Follower\chromedriver.exe'  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver_path))
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Flogin%2F%3F__coig_login%3D1')

time.sleep(2)

username = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
password = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
login = browser.find_element(By.XPATH('/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/button')).click()


username.send_keys(userUser) 
password.send_keys(userPass) 
login.click()

time.sleep(50)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `.click()` method, as such:

```
content = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'content')
content.click()
```

or, somewhat different stylistically, `Keys.ENTER`:

```
username.send_keys(userUser) 
password.send_keys(userPass)
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

the second block of code will submit the web form with a post request on most login forms, and the first block will attempt it as well which should succeed provided all required fields (name and password) are filled out.

Comment: I’ve already been doing that but I’m not sure how to find the login button in the image. Because all I see is class and it just won’t actually find the element when I run it